# Have users use python program for a duration of time

Tags: python, python-3.x, payment

Is it possible to have a program work for a certain amount of time before expiring? For example, I have this code:

```
from time import sleep
import sys

print('Hello')
sleep(200)
print('Still here?')
sys.exit()
```

This code exists after 200 seconds but if a user runs it again it will launch. Is there a way for it to permanently not launch?

Comment: Python is distributed as source (or easily decompilable bytecode). It's fairly trivial to edit out such a check. In practice, if you want to have such a service, the only solution that works against even moderately savvy users is to host it online, so they don't have access to the backend magic.

Comment: This seems to be business question than a python (tech) question. Have you considered using a billing or subscription service? eg. https://stripe.com/au/billing there are many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all use this script to get the current time

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.now())
2009-01-06 15:08:24.789150
```

Then add this to your script

```
import datetime
from time import sleep
import sys

print('Hello')
if '2009-01-06' in datetime.datetime.now():
    pass
else:
    print('Still here?')
    sys.exit()
```

This will expire in 1 day. You can of course customize it to your liking

Answer (score 0):

Just encode the starting time in some string - you can even encrypt it - giving the "key", then your program just has to periodically compare the current time to key+30 days. If reached, just disable access.

Answer (score 0):

Public private key maybe. Or just a token. You could get fancy and collect information about the computer, like the public IP address, the MAC address and so on, to ensure that is is only this person using your software.

Just google how to use python to get this identification of the user.

Maybe it is a good idea to have a database with the information saved for each user, where the user object has an expiration date. and after here the software wont be valid for the user anymore. :)

It will be simple to implement :)